Epson WF7610 - WF 7610 - Scans OK - But will only print blank page
I am a new Ubuntu user, and installed Ubuntu on a new SSD on 23rd April 2024.
My Epson WF 7610 is having problems.
It's a Scanner/Printer.
It scans OK but the print heads do not work, it appears to go through the printing process, but produces a blank page. No sound of the print head being used.
Any ideas ?
